# Can't deploy Angular 9 app with Angular Universal to Firebase with Firebase Functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular9, angular-universal

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.3

Node: 10.16.0

OS: win32 x64

Firebase: 7.9.3

Firebase Tools: 8.6.0
```

There are two tutorials that I was looking at while setting up all this universal and Firebase functions stuff: https://medium.com/@bapittu/angular-9-universal-ssr-with-firebase-and-deployment-in-cloud-function-54867020a656 and https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/

So I added Angular Universal to an existing project by `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` command, it created several files and edited some that already existed. I edited all corresponding paths in `angular.json` to `dist/browser` and `dist/server`.

Command `npm run build:ssr` works well, create dist folder in project root with server and browser folders. Problems appear on the next step. Whether I try to run `npm run serve:ssr` command in root folder, or `firebase serve` after building functions folder, they both emit error: `Error: package.json does not exist at C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\Personal\biz-mate\functions\dist\package.json`.

Having a headache with this issue for a week already, so I'll be extremely grateful for any kind of help.

**UPDATE**

Link to github branch: https://github.com/AnriTapel/biz-mate/tree/at_universal

**UPDATE**

It's all working fine on `localhost:4000` after `npm run serve:ssr`. But when I launch `firebase serve` command, things start to go wrong. In console I got this:

- hosting[biz-mate]: Serving hosting files from: dist/biz-mate/dist/biz-mate/browser
- hosting[biz-mate]: Local server: http://localhost:5000
- functions: Using node@10 from host.
- functions: Watching "C:\Users...\biz-mate\dist\biz-mate" for Cloud Functions...
- functions[ssr]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/.../us-central1/ssr).

When I open first link, page loads correctly with all static files, but ssr function doesn't get executed. When I open function link (http://localhost:5001/.../us-central1/ssr), page open without any static files (404 error in web inspectro), but ssr works.

I'm really sick and tiered of struggling with that ssr issue. Please, please, please, please HELP ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030914/firebase-firestore-not-working-with-angular-universal-package-json-does-not-exi

Comment: @David Thanks, mate, it helped to resolve issues that i mantioned above. But now I have another issue with running firebase serve. I get either `No NgModule metadata found for 'AppServerModule'` or timeout of function executing.

Comment: You need to create a package.json file inside your dist/ folder that is the one your SSR function is going to use when running in Firebase. You need to configure it according to your project, mine has the following dependencies: `firebase-admin`, `firebase-functions`, `@firebase/app`, `@firebase/firestore`

Comment: @SantiBarbat Wow, seems like it help, mate! Deployed successfully & ssr is working! Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: You are welcome @AnriTapel :)

Comment: @SantiBarbat Adding Noticed that meta tags aren't generated during function execution and there're 3 errors in console with same title: `Service installations is not available`. And for meta tags I have separate service that's generating them. Could it be because of some other dependencies should be added?

Comment: For page title and metatags you should use the `Title` and `Meta` services provided by Angular on your ngOnInit method.

Comment: @SantiBarbat No, meta tags service is already created. The problem is when I do `firebase serve`, the page opens successfully, but and error appears in console `app.firestore is not a function`.